# Best way to convert int[][] to int**?

Tags: c#

This is kind of a curiosity question.  I do have an existing solution, but I wonder if people know of a better approach.

My callers want to call me with int[][].  I have a routine that needs to process an int**.  What's the best way to do this conversion?  In other words:

```
public static void Func1(int[][] data) {
  Func2(data); //how to do this?
}

private unsafe static void Func2(int** data) {
  //process data
}
```

Following is the best approach I could come up with.  It works fine, but I can't say I'm 100% happy with the recursive approach (and the O(data.Length) stack space it requires)

```
public static void Main() {
  var test=new[] {
    new [] {10},
    new [] {20,30},
    new [] {40,50,60},
    new [] {70,80,90,100},
  };
  MySolution_Func1(test);
}

public unsafe static void MySolution_Func1(int[][] data) {
  var items=new int*[data.Length];
  Recurse(0, data, items);
}

public unsafe static void Recurse(int index, int[][] data, int*[] build) {
  if(index==data.Length) {
    fixed(int** finalp=build) {
      Func2(finalp);
    }
  } else {
    fixed(int* nextp=data[index]) {
      build[index]=nextp;
      Recurse(index+1, data, build);
    }
  }
}

private unsafe static void Func2(int** data) {
  for(var j=0; j<4; ++j) {
    for(var i=0; i<j+1; ++i) {
      Debug.WriteLine("{0},{1}: {2}", j, i, data[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont mean to hijack, but what is int**?

Comment: ...A pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: @James: a pointer to a pointer to an int: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: You can remove the recursion, but the jagged `int[][]` will require some form of iteration over each "row"... it might be better to just to this *in* the function that first accepted `int**` -- that is, don't massage the data, massage the usage of it. More practical for a "one off" situation. Also, consider `int[,]` and pinning to `int*` with "virtualized indices". Happy coding.

Comment: If you use multi dimensional arrays and unsafe code you should have already found out that you would be much faster with one dimensional arrays. Since you do even allocate memory to get storage space for your pointer pointers before you access the arrays I bet that you would be at least a factor 2-10 faster if you would use one dimensional arrays and a function that takes int *.

Comment: Thanks @Alois.  I agree, and I ended up doing that.  But I was still interested in the question from an "intellectual curiosity" standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to copy the whole array. You can create an array of pointers (i.e. `IntPtr[]`), and then cast that to `int**`. It's not pretty, and I wouldn't suggest doing it. But it can be done. The code below shows how.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[10][];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int[] x = new int[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        x[j] = 10 * i + j;
    }
    myArray[i] = x;
}

// Output the array
Console.WriteLine("int[][]");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", myArray[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Convert to int*[]
unsafe
{
    GCHandle[] handles = new GCHandle[10];
    IntPtr[] ArrayOfPointer = new IntPtr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        handles[i] = GCHandle.Alloc(myArray[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
        ArrayOfPointer[i] = handles[i].AddrOfPinnedObject();
    }
    // Okay, let's output that
    Console.WriteLine("int*[]");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int* p = (int*)ArrayOfPointer[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}, ", *p);
            ++p;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // now convert to int**
    GCHandle bigHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ArrayOfPointer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    int** ppInt = (int**)bigHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // and output it
    Console.WriteLine("int**");
    int** pa = ppInt;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int* p = *pa;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}, ", *p);
            ++p;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        ++pa;
    }

    // Need to free the handles
    bigHandle.Free();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        handles[i].Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool. You're right, I probably won't use this approach, but it's fun to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

```
public unsafe void ConvertToNative(int[][] jarray, out int** ptr)
        {

            ptr= (int**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(jarray.Length*sizeof(int));

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.Length; i++)
            {
                *(ptr+i) = (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(jarray[i].Length*sizeof(int));
                for (int j = 0; j < jarray[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    (*(i + ptr))[j] = jarray[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
```

This works but uses unmanaged memory, and there is no recursion, is that valid ?

Comment: Interesting, though it's kind of a pity that you need to copy every element of the jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with O(1) stack space, if you are willing to copy all the data into another buffer:

```
public unsafe static void AlternateSolution_Func1(int[][] data) {
  var buffer=new int[data.Sum(a => a.Length)];
  fixed(int* pBuffer=buffer) {
    var items=new int*[data.Length];
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<data.Length; ++i) {
      items[i]=pBuffer+count;
      var array=data[i];
      for(int j=0; j<array.Length; ++j) {
        pBuffer[count++]=array[j];
      }
    }
    fixed(int** pItems=items) {
      Func2(pItems);
    }
  }
}
```